# What is the difference between "Drop Down Menu" and "Select Field" in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

It seems that these two instances duplicate each other: [Drop Down Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) and [Select Field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field). Both follow Google Material Design [specs for menus](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html).  The difference is not that obvious at first sight. Why do they provide two similar components?

Answer (score 7):

[Select Field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) has more features that deal with form fields. onChange events, hintText, floatingLabelText.  [Drop Down Menus](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) don't have those features.

Comment: Agree, but what's the advantage (if any ever) of using the Drop Down Menu?

Comment: If you are building a menu the advantages of using Menu are: 1. The inner text of the click target wouldn't change based on your menu selection (selects do that, menus don't) 2. you wouldn't be adding a bunch of unnecessary hidden form inputs to your page 3. You could make it a nested menu 4. You wouldn't confuse the other developers on your team into thinking that it was a form as opposed to a menu.

Answer (score 5):

DropDownMenu is for menus. Imagine a dropdown in the top right with your name 'Green v', you tap it and you see, 'Settings', 'Help', & 'Logout'. Even though it allows you to change the value prop onChange if you want (you could make the menu button say 'Settings v'), that's not what it's supposed to be for. It's actually not intended for use with forms at all, it's just for showing a list of options. Visual: https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#menus-usage

SelectField is for filling in form data, and showing the selected item in the field.